# what if two containers postgres containers mapping the same host volume

Tags: postgresql, docker, persistent-volumes

Actually learning docker,
i manipulate postgres containers and asking myself the
following questions :

I launch a first postgres container like this :

```
docker run -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -p 5464:5432 -v postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

and then a second container, using this command, and by consequence EXACTLY THE SAME VOLUME.

```
docker run -p 5465:5432 -v postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
```

Is it a problem ?
And my most essential question is :
do i have to consider i have two postgres servers sharing the same configurations files,
or do i have to conside i have two postgres containers sharing the same postgres server ?
It's not really clear for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a problem.  I think PostgreSQL is clever enough that one of the databases just won't start up.  In the worst case, this is a recipe for data corruption.  This isn't specific to Docker; just in general, you can't run two databases against the same physical storage.

A typical container-oriented setup is to have two separate databases with two separate volumes, one for each service that requires a database.